# SQL, how to make a search for a user with same ip, or same name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to query a database, I need to group the users that have the same name, or they entered through the same ip, but I have not been able to do a group by, with a condition of type or.
Example:
User (userid, username);
Registration (record_ip, record_date, userid);

Query1:

```
select u.username as Name, r.record_ip as IP
from user u
inner join registration r on u.userid = r.userid;
____________________
| Name   | IP      |
--------------------
| JOSE   | 1.1.1.1 |
| MARIA  | 1.1.2.2 |
| JOSE   | 1.1.2.2 |
| CARLOS | 1.1.2.3 |
| ROBERT | 1.1.1.1 |
--------------------
```

Here, users jose, jose, maria and robert, share something in common, have the same ip, or the same name, and would group together as follows

```
_______________________
|       NAMES         |
-----------------------
| Jose, maria, robert |
| Carlos              |
-----------------------
```

I would like to receive this output.

Comment: This is an interesting project, do let us know if you have a question. If you have a question, then pls share what you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select all the data in you table

```
    class bd{  
        static function connexion(){
            try{
               //LOCAL
                $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name";
                $usr = "username";
                $pass = "password";

                $options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
                $bdd = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pass);
                $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $bdd;
            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }


    static function execQuery($bdd, $query){
        try{
            $req = $bdd->prepare($query);
            $req->execute();
            $result = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $req->closeCursor();
            return $result;
        } catch( PDOEXception $e ) {
               echo $e->getMessage(); // display bdd error
               exit();
           }
       }
    }
    $samename="";
    $bdd = bd::connexion();
    $sql = bd::execQuery($bdd, "SELECT * FROM yourtablename");  
    if(!empty($sql)){
     $lengthn=count($sql);
     for($n=0;$n<$lengthn;$n++){
      for($i=0;$i<$lengthn;$i++){
      if($sql[$n]['IP']==$sql[$i]['IP']){
       $samename+=$sql[$i]['Name'];
      }
      if($i==$lengthn){
      $req = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO newtable (groupname) VALUES('$samename');");
    $samename="";
    }
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up your original query as a derived table called t1.

Have another derived table, t2, that counts if an ip is used once or twice (or more).

Join those two derived tables.

Do `GROUP BY` the ip count. Use `group_concat()` to merge the names together:

```
select group_concat(t1.name) as names
from
(
    select u.username as Name, r.record_ip as IP
    from user u
    inner join registration r on u.userid = r.userid
) t1
join
(
    select r.record_ip as IP, case when count(*) > 1 then 2 else 1 end as ipcnt
    from user u
    inner join registration r on u.userid = r.userid
    group by r.record_ip
) t2
on t1.ip = t2.ip 
group by t2.ipcnt
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
"SELECT `IP` from `users` where `name` = 'JOSE'";
//now you have JOSE IP lets say it $User_ID = '1.1.1.1';
"SELECT name from `users` where `ip` = `$User_ID`;
//now you have ALL names with JOSE IP
```